# How do I recursively read properties of an Object

Tags: c#, recursion, count

I have the following Class. More properties can be added at any time in its life

```
public class Foo
{
    public string propertyA { get; set; }
    public string propertyB { get; set; }
    public string propertyC { get; set; }
}
```

I have an instance of "Foo" and it's populated with the following values

```
   var myFoo = new Foo()
        {
            propertyA = "X valueA",
            propertyB = "valueB",
            propertyC = "X valueC",
        };
```

How do i go about recursively getting the count of the properties (in this example) with the value "X" in its string value?

Comment: *More properties can be added at any time in its life* - I don't understand; more properties are only added as a dev effort (type more code, compile, release)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the Expected Value of X?

you can loop it with a function like that:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: you could add that you can access the value by accessing `propertyInfo.Value()`